# WCF UserName Authentication: Can I get the Username in a custom ServiceAuthorizationManager?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, authorization

I have a WCF service that is using a custom `ServiceAuthorizationManager`. The custom auth manager is already set up to handle Windows and Forms authentication.

However, if I connect with a client that is set to `UserName` auth, I can't seem to find the username anywhere.

The client code looks like this:

```
this.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
this.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";
this.Open();
this.MyMethod(); // my actual contract method
this.Close();
```

Then on the server, I have my custom auth manager:

```
public sealed class AppAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    public override bool CheckAccess(OperationContext operationContext, ref Message message)
    {
        // would like to check user/pwd here...
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

- The `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is not set,
- `operationContext.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity` is not set.
- `operationContext.ServiceSecurityContext.AuthorizationContext.ClaimSets` is empty.

Is the user/pwd supposed to be available anywhere? Or do I have to add a custom `UsernamePasswordValidator` too?

---

**Update:** So I added a custom `UserNamePasswordValidator` and an `IAuthorizationPolicy`.
My updated WCF config looks like this:

```xml
<behavior name="Server2ServerBehavior">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom" serviceAuthorizationManagerType="MyApp.AuthManager, MyApp">
    <authorizationPolicies>
      <add policyType="MyApp.TokenAuthorizationPolicy, MyApp" />
    </authorizationPolicies>
  </serviceAuthorization>
  <serviceCredentials>
    <userNameAuthentication customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyApp.PFUserNameValidator, MyApp" />
  </serviceCredentials>
</behavior>
```

If I set a breakpoint in all 3 of those classes, WCF throws the exception:

```
LogonUser failed for the 'username' user. Ensure that the user has a valid Windows account.
   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.WindowsUserNameSecurityTokenAuthenticator.ValidateUserNamePasswordCore(String userName, String password)
```

Before any of them are run. Hmmm...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is normally handled in the [UsernamePasswordValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354513.aspx) - which is the only place you'll have access to the password. However, this isn't where you set the principal - that would be in the `IAuthorizationPolicy`'s `Evaluate` method, which might look something like:

```
bool IAuthorizationPolicy.Evaluate(
    EvaluationContext evaluationContext, ref object state)
{           
    IList<IIdentity> idents;
    object identsObject;
    if (evaluationContext.Properties.TryGetValue(
        "Identities", out identsObject) && (idents =
        identsObject as IList<IIdentity>) != null)
    {
        foreach (IIdentity ident in idents)
        {
            if (ident.IsAuthenticated &&
                ident.AuthenticationType == TrustedAuthType)
            {                           
                evaluationContext.Properties["Principal"]
                    = //TODO our principal
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!evaluationContext.Properties.ContainsKey("Principal"))
    {
        evaluationContext.Properties["Principal"] = //TODO anon
    }                
    return false;
}
```

(where `TrustedAuthType` is the name of our password validator)

With this in place, the thread's principal will be set, and we can identify ourselves (and use roles-based security etc)

Comment: Thanks! For anyone who may need it later on, here is how to add a custom AuthorizationPolicy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729794.aspx

Comment: What could be the problem if the "Identities" is null? I'm having a "custom" principalPermissionMode too and an AuthorizationPolicy just like you have in your example

Comment: @Juri - then it sounds like they are anonymous... beyond that, hard to answer.

Comment: I solved the "Identities" problem, was an issue that locally on my workstation it didn't work properly. However, the problem I got afterwards was that I had to impersonate my identity which was not possibly at the stage of custom authorization policies. Therefore I went this approach which I documented in my blog post (if someone happens to have the same problem): http://blog.js-development.com/2010/11/intercepting-wcf-operation-calls-with.html

Comment: Could you please take a look at this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45770217/my-customauthorizationpolicy-evaluate-method-never-fires