# Infering Credentials with WCF

Tags: iphone, wcf, authentication, basic-authentication, http-authentication

I need to get a list of tasks for a user from a WCF service to display on an iPhone app. I'm planning to use something like http://www.nayyeri.net/custom-username-and-password-authentication-in-wcf-3-5 to authenticate, but how would I pick up the username/user ID to filter my list of items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to follow the example in the answer to this [question on custom validator access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529485/wcf-username-authentication-can-i-get-the-username-in-a-custom-serviceauthorizat) to the user name. This [good overview of custom service credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730868.aspx) shows how all the pieces work together. On the iPhone side, you'll need to configure the client to perform Basic HTTP authentication over HTTPS to successfully call the service.